# iPhone + NSString error

Tags: iphone, nsstring, cfstring

I have static `NSString` as below:

```
static NSString *bowlerName;
```

In the code I am assigning it with some value as below:

```
 -(void)setBowlerSpecifications:(int)playerId
 {  
  Player *objPlayer =  [CricketManagementDAL getBowlerSpecification :playerId];
  [objPlayer retain];
  bowlerSpecialSkill = objPlayer.specialSkill;
  bowlerType = objPlayer.type;
  bowlerName = objPlayer.playerName; // <------------
  [objPlayer release];
 }
```

Now, if I am referring to the same variable `bowlerName` in code anywhere else, I get the error:

```
Variable is not a CFString.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an NSString but you are using it elsewhere in a context that expects a CFString, you can simply cast as follows

```
CFStringRef aCFString = (CFStringRef)aNSString;
```

Comment: I don't understand I have the same problem, but I'm using it in a context that expects NSStrings...